# How to name entity of class automatically? Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

I have a class `Shape` and 3 classes:

```
Triangle: Shape, Rectangle: Shape, Triangle: Shape
```

I read a `String` from input, and after that I need to draw that shape.

How I can automatically name the instances of classes, when I parse the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have class `Shape` and its subclasses

```
class Shape { 
}

class Triangle: Shape {   
}

class Rectangle: Shape {   
}
```

then you can create static method for `Shape` which returns certain `Shape` depending on given input

```
class Shape {

    class func instantiate(name: String) -> Shape? {
        switch name.lowercased() {
        case "triangle":
            return Triangle()
        case "rectangle":
            return Rectangle()
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

---

Usage:

```
if let triangle = Shape.instantiate(name: someText) as? Triangle {
    // work with triangle
} else if let rectangle = Shape.instantiate(name: someText) as? Rectangle {
    // work with rectangle
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create `enum` and use it to switch between the cases the user input,

Something like this,

```
enum ClassType: String {
    case triangle = "triangle"
    case rectangle = "rectangle"
}

func getClass(with name: String) -> Shape?  {
switch ClassType(rawValue: name.lowercased()){
case .triangle?: print("Triangle")
    return Triangle()
case .rectangle?: print("Recangle")
    return Rectangle()
case .none:
    print("not found")
    return nil
}
}
```

> **Test** : `getClass(with: "Triangle")`  **Result** : Triangle

Another way but i don't really recommend is checking on the class name description like this.

```
 func drawMyShape(name: String) {
    if name == String(describing: Rectangle.self){
        print("Rect")
    } else if name == String(describing: Triangle.self) {
        print("Triangle")
    }
}
drawMyShape(name: "Rectangle")
```

Comment: you mean class, thats another topic however this is how you can get what the user entered if it was triangle or rectangle use this information to make what u need , please explain more what you mean by entity ?

Comment: oh, sorry, my bad. how i can create an instance of classes? to work with it

Comment: simply  inside each case, ill comment them out for you ^_^

Comment: something like that:
        let circle = Circle()
        circle.radius = 400
        array.append(circle),
automatically